# How to run job in only one pod using @Scheduled in Spring Boot

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I'm using @Scheduled annotation to schedule a job in Spring Boot. My code is running in Kubernetes cluster. Job is working fine, but when I start multiple pods, each pod starts running the job at the given time.
I want only one to run the job.
Read about Shedlock but it doesn't seem to work with Firestore database.
Is there a way to achieve this behaviour with Firestore database?

Answer (score 0):

First, why would you want to scale your scheduled job? scheduled job should not be scaled. It's better if you separate it with the micro-service arc in mind.

if your concern is price, so that you want to combine your scheduled job with other services, I dont think that `Firestore` could help you in this case. Rather, you could change your scheduler into a Http server, and use `Google Cloud Scheduler` to invoke your pod.